# sql; concatenate MIN(price) and MAX(price) into column?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I am working on an aws athena query like so:

```
SELECT 
    normalised_brand, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT merch1) merch1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT category_level_1) category_level_1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(*) product_distinct_count,
    MIN(effective_price) maxprice, 
    MAX(effective_price) minprice 
    -- CONCAT_WS(' - ', minprice, maxprice) price_range
    
FROM "db" 
WHERE product_gap = 'yes' AND store_name = 'petco'
group by normalised_brand
```

Which will give results like so:

[image]

Right now I have maxprice and minprice as two separate columns, but I want to combine them into one column "price range" which will have minprice and maxprice separated by a " - " string, so it would look something like this:

```
price_range
3.99 - 5.33
2.11 - 9.99
2.22 - 2.22
```

I tried doing this by adding CONCAT but wasn't getting working results. Im very new to sql and am wondering how I could potentially create this price range column by combining the MAX() and MIN() results into a string value.

Also, I it possible to add logic to SQL so that if the price range is zero (like in the case of 2.22 - 2.22 where max price and minprice are identical) to just display a single value instead of a price range with identical max/min values?

this last part is a stretch goal, first im just trying to create the price_range column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()`

```
SELECT 
    normalised_brand, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT merch1) merch1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT category_level_1) category_level_1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(*) product_distinct_count,
    MIN(effective_price) maxprice, 
    MAX(effective_price) minprice 
    concat(cast(MIN(effective_price) as varchar(10)),'-',cast(MAX(effective_price) as varchar(10)))
FROM "db" 
WHERE product_gap = 'yes' AND store_name = 'petco'
group by normalised_brand
```

Comment: tried adding that line but got an error: ```line 8:5: extraneous input 'concat' expecting {<eof>, ',', 'from', 'where', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'union', 'except', 'intersect'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;```

Comment: I tried adding a couple more ')' parenthesis at the end of the cast statements because it seemed like it was missing one: ```concat(
      cast(MIN(effective_price) as varchar(10)),
      '-',
      cast(MAX(effective_price) as varchar(10)),
     )``` same issue though

Comment: @Martin, I've updated the answer - parenthesis was missing

Comment: thanks, im running this in aws athena, dealing with this err ```extraneous input 'concat' expecting {<eof>, ',', 'from', 'where', 'group', 'order', 'having', 'limit', 'union', 'except', 'intersect'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;``` related to the new concat() line, im going to try and test concat with some other values

Comment: it has to do with the ```cast(MIN(effective_price) as varchar(10)``` statement not working, if i replace the three values in concat with strings like 'A','B','C' it works, but the cast statement is what causes the err, im looking into it

Comment: i got it, had to put the cast expression in parenthesis like so: ```CONCAT(CAST(MIN(effective_price) as varchar(10)),' - ', CAST(MAX(effective_price) as varchar(10)))``` thank you

Comment: casting is not required. Try without casting.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85668/44

Comment: @Martin, glad that it helped u

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    normalised_brand, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT merch1) merch1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT category_level_1) category_level_1_distinct_count,
    COUNT(*) product_distinct_count,
    MIN(effective_price) maxprice, 
    MAX(effective_price) minprice, 
    CONCAT( MIN(effective_price),'-' , MAX(effective_price)) price_range
    
FROM "db" 
WHERE product_gap = 'yes' AND store_name = 'petco'
group by normalised_brand
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85668/44